# date gets increased by a day

Tags: mongodb, momentjs

I have a date in my mongodb database in following format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8cd5e5cf36cb517c91910e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z")
}
```

When I show it by using moment on front end it gets increased by one day so `2018-09-04` becomes `2018-09-05`

On front end I do this

```
moment(date).format('dddd MMM DD, YYYY')
```

I want same date extracted from the database that is `2018-09-04`

Any help is appreciated.

Edit ->

When I console it on back end I see this

```
date: 2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z
```

And on front end

```
date: "Thu Sep 06 2018 05:28:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

Comment: Why not just simply increase the day by one in your front-end code whenever you retrieve the data?

Comment: When  I subtract one day on front end other dates which are in same format are also gets subtracted... It only increases day only for the dates which are having time 23:58 or above then 22:00

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb stores dates in ISO formats, it depends on where (in what timezones) your server and client are located. You can use the below.
The format for date you are getting is UTC format, when it will get converted to IST, it would show the difference. It means the following :-

If I get 2019-09-26T18:30:00.000Z as date in UTC. It is equivalent to Fri Sep 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). Please look at the difference 5hrs 30 mins. Incrementing/decrementing any thing on this and showing in IST would be wrong again as per the timezone is concerned.

If you do

```
new Date(date).toUTCString()
```

It will show you "Thu, 26 Sep 2019 18:30:00 GMT" In GMT which is exact.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a timezone issue.

If I run 

`console.log(moment('2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z').utcOffset("+00:00").format());
console.log(moment('2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z').utcOffset("+05:30").format());
console.log(moment('2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z').utcOffset("+00:00").format('dddd MMM DD, YYYY'));
console.log(moment('2018-09-04T23:58:00.000Z').utcOffset("+05:30").format('dddd MMM DD, YYYY'));`

I get 

`2018-09-04T23:58:00Z
2018-09-05T05:28:00+05:30
Tuesday Sep 04, 2018
Wednesday Sep 05, 2018`

Which is off by one day